# Как предотвратить повторное добавление записи в БД при обновлении страницы?

Tags: php

Всем привет!
Я реализовал форму с комментариями на сайте, вроде как бы работает, но с косяками, при обновлении страницы вылазит форма подтверждения повторной отправки, а также повторное добавление записи в БД. Как избавиться от этого? Знаю за редирект, пробовал его, но все без толку, возможно я его неправильно использую... В общем, помогите, заранее спасибо! :)

Страница с отдельным постом и формой (post.php):

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/connect.php';
require_once 'includes/function.php';
require_once 'includes/header.php';

$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
$separate_post = get_post_by_id($post_id);
$categories = get_category($connect);
add_comment($connect);
$result = pin_comment($connect);
?>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<!-- Post Content Column -->
<div class="col-lg-8">

<!-- Title -->
<h1 class="mt-4"><?php echo $separate_post['title']; ?></h1>


<hr>
<!-- Date/Time -->
<p>Опубликовано: <?php echo $separate_post['datetime']; ?></p>

<hr>

<!-- Preview Image -->
<img class="img-fluid rounded" src="<?php echo $separate_post['image']; ?>" 
alt="">

<hr>

<!-- Post Content 
<p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
Ducimus, vero, obcaecati, aut, error quam sapiente nemo saepe quibusdam sit 
excepturi nam quia corporis eligendi eos magni recusandae laborum minus 
inventore?</p>
-->
<p><?php echo $separate_post['text']; ?></p>


<!-- Comments Form -->
<div class="card my-4">
<h5 class="card-header">Оставить комментарий:</h5>
<div class="card-body">
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше Имя:" name="name"> 
<br>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="text"></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Single Comment     -->
<?php foreach($result as $res) { ?>
<div class="media mb-4">
<img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" 
alt="">
<div class="media-body">
<h5 class="mt-0"><?php echo $res['name'];?></h5>
<?php echo $res['text'];?>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Файл с функциями (function.php)

```
function add_comment($connect){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
if(!empty($_POST)){
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments (`name`, `text`) VALUES ('$name', '$text')";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
return $result;
}
}

function pin_comment($connect){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
return $result;
}
```

header.php

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/connect.php';
require_once 'includes/function.php';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink- 
to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Тестовый блог</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/blog-home.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Тестовый блог</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria- 
expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link" href="/">Главная
<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Связаться со мной</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

И ещё вопрос, как правильно сделать то, чтобы для каждой отдельной страницы были свои комментарии? (Привязать к таблицу с комментами id поста и получать его значение через GET от post.php или как)?

Comment: Насчет второго вопроса вы правы. Нужно добавить колонку post_id в таблицу с комментариями, и в запросе выбирать комменты по условию:
`SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id=:post_Id`.    

P.S. Всегда используйте плейсхолдеры в sql запросах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции `add_comment` вместо `return` добавьте следующее:

```
$url = (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")) ? "https" : "http";
$url .= "://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
header("Location: {$url}");
```

Таким образом после добавления записи в таблицу будет делаться редирект на текущую страницу.

Для привязки комментария к посту вам нужно добавить поле которое будет хранить ID записи, например `post_id`. И когда вы делаете `INSERT` необходимо будет сохранять этот ID.

И соответственно когда вы получаете комментарии вам нужно будет добавить условие `WHERE post_id = $post_id` для фильтрации комментариев по ID записи.

Так же рекомендую почитать про SQL-инъекции. И для работы с БД использовать хотя бы [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) и не вставлять полученные от пользователя данные в БД в необработанном виде.

Comment: не пашет, выдаёт ошибку:
`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\heyoneblog\includes\header.php:7) in D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\heyoneblog\includes\function.php on line 55`

Comment: @heyone
Добавьте в свой вопрос содержимое файла header.php

Comment: добавил header.php

Comment: Опустите подключение хедера ниже, он должен быть непосредственно перед HTML кодом на текущей странице.

Comment: у меня комп перезапустился после обновления страницы, плюс вылазит предупреждение о том что подключение небезопасно

Comment: ща все норм, единственное что вылазит предупреждение об опасном соединении

Comment: Ну перезагрузка с этим не связана) А вот сообщение о соединении подключении связана с ошибкой в условии. Исправил строчку: $url = (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")) ? "https" : "http";

Comment: еееее, всё заработало, спасибо огромное! :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не забудьте пометить ответ как ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: нажал, вот что выдало:
Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.

Comment: @heyone Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как решение вопроса.

Comment: по поводу фильтрации комментариев, привязку делать к GET-значению? У каждой страницы есть свой id, получается нужно присваивать это значение к таблице с комментариями к ячейке post_id?

Comment: Да, всё правильно.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое дружище))) Здоровья побольше тебе и счастья! :)